# Subversion oddity - svn info revision higher than last changed rev on project folder

Tags: svn, version-control, msbuild, revision

Got something going on I can't explain.

I have a working copy of my project - done svn update (which says: Updated to revision 1895), I know it's the latest. When I perform an `svn info` on the project folder, the Revision is 1895, but the Last Changed Rev is 1888.

Inspecting the log using TortoiseSVN shows 1888 as the last revision, no trace of 1895. An `svn log` on 1895 is empty, and an `svn diff` between 1895 and 1888 is empty as well, ie. no differences.

How did I somehow end up with some rogue revision that hasn't really changed anything? It basically is causing the build server (thinks it's on 1888) to be out of sync with my MSBuild SvnVersion task (thinks revision is 1895).

Any suggestions appreciated.

**Edit:** If Revision will always show the latest revision for the whole repository, it means that things like SvnVersion MSBuild task (which uses svnversion.exe, but exhibits similar behaviour) don't display the correct revision for when you have a multiple project single repository, you will need to use "Last Changed Rev" for your version number.

As a result, now rolling my own SvnLastChangedRev MSBuild task.

Comment: It's actually not a huge deal that it is the whole repo: if you checkout that revision, you'll still get the correct copy of your code for that project, and be able to build it again. If you are using something like CruiseControl, set up to only build on changes, then you're not going to get a new version for that project (assuming it's the only thing checked out) anyways.

Comment: did you get anywhere with your SvnLastChangedRev MSBuild task? As im having a similar issue

Comment: @James - yes, I've published a bunch of useful MSBuild tasks on CodePlex, which includes the SvnLastChangedRev one. See: http://zealanditmsbuild.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not a problem or an oddity... the revision number applies to the entire Subversion repository, and therefore, the revision number may be higher due to changes elsewhere in the repository than the last revision number at which something changed in the branch of the repository in which you are working.

To clarify, if you commit to `trunk`, bringing the repository to revision 10, and then a whole slew of changes in `branches` and `tags` brings the repository to revision 1000, then 10 will be the "last changed revision" for the `trunk` folder, but the current revision number of the entire repository would be 1000.

Comment: I'm aware of revision number being global per repository. But when I perform an update in a working folder which is some hierarchy levels down the repository tree, I'd never noticed it would update to latest revision globally, just to the latest for that path.

Comment: @WimHollebrandse You will see the updated revision globally only when you run svn update at the root of the checkout/repository. Subversion will never update the metadata for parent directories.